# Normalisation in feature extraction using pre-trained model

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, normalization, feature-engineering, z-score

I have a dataset with medical images. I want to implement a network for super-resolution using GANs. One of the criteria of the optimisation is a perceptual loss. For that I will use a pretrained vgg network, trained on imagenet solely to extract features. Essentially, this vgg network is used as a feature extractor. I feed my network with data normalized with the medical dataset statistics. Therefore the output are images with the dataset statistics as well.

When I want to extract features from the output of my network should I simply pass the output of my network to the vgg since it is already normalized with the medical dataset statistics or do I need to denormalize back the network output and then normalize with the imagenet statistics?